# Entries Field save errors

Tags: craft3, entries-field, 3.7

I'm running into some odd behavior with an entries field. There are multiple entries fields on the site and all work as expected but one. The behavior is as follows.

- If there are multiple entries already associated, rearranging the entries (drag and drop) and then saving will clear all entries from the field.
- Saving more than one entry to the field at a time (in one save event, not in total) will remove everything but the most recently clicked entry.
- Saving entries individually, adding an entry, saving, adding another, saving, etc. is the only way currently to add multiple entries to the field.

Some further details:

- The field has worked correctly for a long time until recently. The site was updated from Craft 3.1 to 3.7. I believe this is when it stopped working.
- The production site runs on PHP 7.2.24. When I run my local on a similar version, I can recreate the error, but upping my local PHP to 7.4.1 removes the issue. Updating the PHP version of the production site is not an option at this time.
- I've checked the craft logs as well as the php error logs and mysql logs. No errors appear, nor is an error thrown when saving, not even a flash message error.

Comment: As of Craft 3.6.0, PHP version 7.2.5 is required. https://github.com/craftcms/cms/blob/develop/CHANGELOG.md#360---2021-01-26 That might be the issue.

Comment: @CraftQuest I mentioned above, but the site currently exceeds 7.2.5. It's on php 7.2.24. Running my local on 7.2.33 also recreates the problem. So the issue does seem to be tied to a lower PHP version, but the site does exceed the minimum reqs from Craft.